# django override get - templateview

Tags: django

I want to override get method in templateview:

```
class ...

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.is_ajax():
        #do and return something
    return super(self, Clasname).get(request, *args, **kwargs) #when not ajax
```

This is giving error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Must be type, not <classname>

Comment: Full traceback please, or at least the error and line. This will help others when they search for that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the arguments to `super`, i.e.,

```
return super(Clasname, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```